# VScode intellisense wants me to import View component from react-native/type but not react-native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to import **View** component from **react-native**, on invoking intellisense in VScode it wants me to import it from **react-native/types** but not **react-native**

It's working on my old projects, but this time I created a new react native application v0.71.3

[image]

Comment: You are importing components not a type definition. `react-native/types` mislead intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem recently.
You can resolve this by adding `@types/react-native` to your project.
Specifically doing `yarn add -D @types/react-native` if you're using Yarn.
If you're using `npm install --save @types/react-native`
This should address the bummed imports intelligence is recommending.